# split comma(','), full stop('.') and space (' ') from a string without using split function, append string's word in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to split comma ',', full stop '.' and white space ' ' from a string without using any build-in split function, and append those word in list.

Input:
"Hi, Welcome to MK training. I love python."

Expected output:
['Hi', 'Welcome', 'to', 'MK', 'training', 'I', 'love', 'python']

Here is my code that I tried:

```
s = "Hi, Welcome to MK training. I love python."
c_pos = -1
last_pos = - 1
r = []
for i in s[c_pos+1:]:
  if i == ' ' or i == ',' or i == '.':
      c_pos = s.index(i, c_pos+1)
      r.append(s[last_pos+1:c_pos])
      last_pos = c_pos

print(r)
```

Output:
['Hi', '', 'Welcome', 'to', 'MK', 'training', '', 'I', 'love', 'python']

I know if If I use list remove() method, I can erase '' from list and I'll get my expected output. What I want is, do all operation with string and split comma, full stop, and white space from string without using any split function, and append those word in a list. Don't want to do anything with list.

Comment: If we do your homework for you how will you learn?

Comment: it's not my home work. I solve a problem by myself by removing only white space. Now I modified that problem and  seeking for solution.

Comment: Hint: Right now, you're appending to 'r' the moment you find a separator character. Instead, hold off appending until you find a non-separator character. That will allow you to ignore consecutive separators.

Comment: Um, the string says "Welcome to MK training". That, and the nature of the task makes it pretty clear this is homework. Nothing wrong with asking for help with your homework as long as you are honest about it and show that you have made a good faith effort to solve the problem yourself and only need a hint.

Comment: @KurtisRader the problem I solve was like split the word from 'Welcome to HKR training'. After solving that, I modified that problem on my own version. MK is the abbreviation of my full name

Comment: Hint #1: Iterate over the string rather than index into it: `for c in s:`. Hint #2: Use a bool to know whether you are currently accumulating characters or skipping separator characters. And that is as much help you deserve since you still refuse to acknowledge this is basically homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
data = 'Hi, Welcome to MK training. I love python.'

words = []
word = ''

# loop through each character
for x in data:

    print('Processing ' + x)

    # if character is a separator and if word variable has something in it
    # then store it in words list
    if x in [',', '.', ' ']:
        
        print('!! Found a separator !!')

        if word:
            print(f'Adding the word "{word}" to {words}. Resetting word.')
            words.append(word)
            word = ''
            print(f'Words is now {words}')

    else:
        word += x
        print(f'Word is {word}')

# after looping through all characters, if there's still something
# in word, store it in words list
if word:
    words.append(word)

print(words)
```

Example: https://www.ideone.com/DYPsem

## Explanation

If the input was "Hello, there", we loop through each character.

- We check if the character was a separator. H is not. So, we store it in word
- We check e, which is not a separator. So, we add it behind H to make He
- We check l and our word becomes Hel
- We do the same with the 2nd. Our word is now Hell
- We do that with o. Our word is now Hello
- Then we hit `,`. That's a separator. So, we ask: is there anything in word? Yes! There's Hello
- Great! We add Hello to words list and words becomes ['Hello']
- We move on to  , which is a separator. We ask: is there anything in word? No. Word is empty. So, do nothing.
- We continue doing that and loop through all characters

When you reach the end, if there is not a separator then word will contain `there`. So, one last time we ask: Is there anything in word? If there is, add it to words. So, words becomes ['Hello', 'there']

Give it a shot.